# Solve the following trigonometric equation: $3\sin^2(x) - \sin(x) - 2 = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve $3\sin^2(x) - \sin(x) - 2 = 0$ on the interval $[0, 2\pi)$

I have two of the solutions, but I can't find the solution in Q III.

First I factor..

$(3\sin(x) + 2)(\sin(x) - 1) = 0$

$3\sin(x) + 2 = 0$ or $\sin(x) = 1$

$\sin(x) = 1$ yields $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$

The first equation has the solution $x = \arcsin(\frac{-2}{3}) = -0.729727656$ rad.  When I add $2\pi$ to this, I get $5.5535$ rad, which is in quadrant IV, but there is another solution in quadrant III.  How can I get the solution in quadrant III?

Comment: Use $\sin (\pi - x) = \sin x$

Answer (score 1):

That first value ($-0.79729656...$) gives you a location in the fourth quadrant in terms of its (angular) distance from the $x$-axis. That distance should be the same for the corresponding third quadrant point, because they have the same $y$-coordinate. This time, though, the distance is in the positive direction, past $\pi$, so you want $\pi + 0.79729656...=\pi-\sin^{-1}\frac{-2}3$.

The identity in use is: $\sin(\pi-\theta)=\sin\theta.$

Answer (score 1):

Given $a\in(-1,1)$, there are *two distinct* angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$ such that $\sin\alpha=a=\sin\beta$.

For instance, $\sin(\pi/3)=\sin(2\pi/3)$: just realize that the line $y=a$ cuts the unit circle in two points.

One of these angles is in the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and is denoted by $\arcsin a$; the other one, up to integral multiples of $2\pi$ is $\pi-\arcsin a$.

So the solutions of an elementary equation $\sin x=a$ are
$$
x=\arcsin a+2k\pi \quad\text{or}\quad x=\pi-\arcsin a+2k\pi
$$
These solution sets coincide if and only if $a=1$ or $a=-1$, because the line $y=a$ in these cases is tangent to the unit circle.

In your case, $\pi-(-0.729727656)\approx3.871320309$ and
$$
3.871320309-2\pi\approx-2.411864997
$$
which is the other solution in the third quadrant.